# Когда пытаюсь добавить картинку получаю ошибку

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, img, jsx

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Привет!Когдая пытаюсь добавить картинку на сайт то получаю вот такую ошибку[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Использую react-create-app.

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../App.css';
import FaAlignJustify from 'react-icons/lib/fa/align-justify';
class Header extends Component {
     render() {
         return(
         <div>
             <FaAlignJustify />
             <img src="D:\projects\portland.com\src\images\portland.png" alt="portlandlogo"/>
             <div>
                 <ul>
                     <li>Home</li>
                     <li>Devices</li>
                     <li>Delivery & Payment</li>
                     <li>Guarantee</li>
                     <li>About Us</li>
                 </ul>
             </div>
         </div>);


    }
}

export default Header;
```

Расскажите пожалуйста с чем это связано и как решить эту ошибку?

Изменил путь на вот такой `<img src="./images/portland.png" alt="portlandlogo"/>` и ошибка исчезла, но картинка по прежнему не отображается[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: Структура папок]

Comment: Да, действительно.
у меня было так -
Папка src содержала и components и assets, подумал так быстрее путь прописать. Работает только из паблика, предполагаю, что из за того что когда это все компилится, он в src только код хочет видеть и некаких больше вечеринок.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по структуре сайта, путь к картинке должен быть таким:

```
<img src="../images/portland.png" alt="portlandlogo"/>
```

Сейчас вы пытаетесь загрузить картинку из той же директории где лежит Header, вам нужно выйти из директории Components в src. Почитайте про относительные и абсолютные пути, когда нужна ./ а когда ../

**Решение:**
Переместите папку images в public, а в src напишите /images/portland.png

Comment: Все равно не работает

Comment: Сейчас обратил внимание, что у вас в примере кода portland.png, а на скрине из студии portland.jpg. Расширение совпадают?

Comment: Добавил скриншот,разные форматы изза того что тестировал вдруг с расширением что то не так.

Comment: Переместите папку images в public и в src напишите /images/portland.png

Comment: Работает))Но теперь мне вобоще не понятно как так получается что в public работает а в src -нет.

Comment: Для этого нужно разбираться с webpack-ом, можете посмотреть https://learn.javascript.ru/screencast/webpack

Answer (score 0):

нужно ставить картинку в ту папку, где находиться индекс.хтмл файл и путь писать от туда. тогда все гуд

Comment: Полагаю, Вы, немного опоздали, вопрос был задан 4 года назад)

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, будет полезно таким же новичкам, как я. Изображения или папку к ним нужно помещать обязательно в public