# Подключение статических файлов при сборке react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

**Задача:** пытаюсь подключить статические файлы (картинки, шрифты). В dev версии всё ок, пытаюсь собрать - получаю ряд ошибок, суть которых в том, что все пути становятся не правильными, даже те которые в index.html

Сейчас имею следующую базовую структуру

```
public
   img
      Pattern.png, Photo.png
   index.html
src
   components
      card
         card.css
         card.js
      app.js
      app.css
```

В `card.js` кое-как подключить смог `<img src="img/Photo.png" />`.

Теперь пытаюсь подключить в `app.css`:

```
.app {
    background: url('../../public/img/Pattern.png');
}
```

В dev такая запись работает, но при сборке пути не верные получаются: `F:/static/media/Pattern.7858f3d0f9b100e9018a.png`.

Пробовал другие варианты записи, но эффект такой же либо ошибка при сборке, пишет что не видит файл. Приложение создал через cra, собираю через `react-scripts build`.

**Вопросы:**

- как мне успешно собрать приложение?
- правильно ли я создал структуру приложения?
- почему происходит неверная генерация пути даже в файле index.html, можно ли это исправить?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как в Create React App использовать папку images внутри src/?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1239945/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-create-react-app-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%ba%d1%83-images-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8-src)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Когда пытаюсь добавить картинку получаю ошибку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/779643/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%8E-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D1%83)

Comment: Подключение файлов работает при разработке, но не работает при сборке. Приведённые вопросы нацелены именно на проблему подключения при разработке

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Webpack не помещает картинки при сборке в папку dist](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1018695/webpack-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D1%83-dist)